# Checking value in different df and summing up values in an other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im' struggling to do something easy on panda (by the way I'm not really confortable with pandas).

I have 2 dataframes :

df1

```
Thing   2010    2011    2012
Banana  37  40  56
Pear    15  37  55
Carrot  7   4   30
```

And an other one

df2

```
    Fruits  Banana  Pear
    Vegetables  Carrot
```

And what I want is something like this :

```
        2010    2011    2013
Fruits   52      77     111 
Vegetables 7      4      30
```

What I tried to do, is first check if the fruit from df1 is in df2, then I wanted to append it to list to finally sum up the values, but it seems confused...

I've just started to check but it tells me "False"... where as there are values matching...

```
df1.Thing.isin(df2)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: df2 doesn't really look like a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Idea is create dictionary by values by `Fruits,Vegetables` and then aggregate `sum` with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': {'Fruits': 'Banana', 'Vegetables': 'Carrot'}, 
                    'b': {'Fruits': 'Pear', 'Vegetables': np.nan}})
print (df2)
                 a     b
Fruits      Banana  Pear
Vegetables  Carrot   NaN


d = df2.stack().reset_index(name='new').set_index('new')['level_0'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'Banana': 'Fruits', 'Pear': 'Fruits', 'Carrot': 'Vegetables'}

df = df1.groupby(df1['Thing'].map(d)).sum()
print (df)
            2010  2011  2012
Thing                       
Fruits        52    77   111
Vegetables     7     4    30
```